# What does "beat the birds" mean?

Tags: meaning, lyrics, songs

Heard this phrase in Frank Sinatra's song.

> Just say the words and we'll beat the birds Down to Acapulco Bay

Just wonder what that means. I have rough idea, just to go to Acapulco Bay. Want to understand exact flavor of it.

Comment: We will fly faster that the birds Down to Acapulco Bay....

Comment: Birds, that is, in their annual southward migration to avoid the northern-hemisphere winter.

Answer (score 0):

I understand it as beating someone in a competition, winning against the birds in a race, being faster than the birds.